# How to loop through a range of data, copy a template for each unique ID in the data, and fill in the template

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to write a VBA script to sort through a list of clients in which each client (one per row) has a specific group name. There are multiple clients per group. The macro should:

- Copy a template form for each unique group into a new tab
- Rename the tab with the group name
- Fill in information of each member of the group into the group form
- Move on to the next group and repeat the process until all groups have their own tab containing relevant information about each client in the group

I've gotten the macro to repeat the process once but then it stops after copying the template a second time and doesn't rename the tab according to the group name. Perhaps there is a simple loop statement I'm leaving out? Code is below. Thanks!

```
 Sub ContractPopulate()

 Dim wrk As Workbook
 Dim trg As Worksheet
 Dim datasheet As Worksheet
 Dim TRow As Long
 Dim BRow As Long
 Dim C_PR As Range
 Dim GrpCnt As Long
 Dim rng As String
 Dim rngcnt As Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook
TRow = 2 'Start at the first group
Set datasheet = wrk.Worksheets("Data")

Sheets("Contract").Select
Sheets("Contract").Copy After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count)
Set trg = wrk.ActiveSheet
trg.Copy After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count)
trg.Name = datasheet.Cells(TRow, 8).Value

GrpCnt = 0 'Reset group count to 0 -to begin counting groups?

 'Copy FO, paste to row 7, column B
Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 6), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 6))
trg.Cells(7, 2) = C_PR.Value

 'Copy group name, paste row 7, column W
Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 8), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 8))
trg.Cells(7, 23) = C_PR.Value

 'Copy cell name, paste row 8, column B
Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 5), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 5))
trg.Cells(8, 2) = C_PR.Value

'Copy unique group ID to row 8, coulmn U (hidden by white text)
Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 7), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 7))
trg.Cells(8, 21) = C_PR.Value

 'Count groups again?
rng = datasheet.Cells(TRow, 7).Value


 Do While rng = trg.Cells(8, 21) 'Uses the hidden Unique Group Name to count the number of clients to enter from datasheet

 'Copying client last name and dropping it in worksheet row one down from top, column H
Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 9), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 9))
trg.Cells(12 + (TRow - 1) * 3, 8) = C_PR.Value

 'Copying client first name and dropping it in worksheet row trow one down from top, column T
Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 10), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 10))
trg.Cells(12 + (TRow - 1) * 3, 20) = C_PR.Value

 'Copy National ID
Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 13), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 13))
trg.Cells(13 + (TRow - 1) * 3, 4) = C_PR.Value

 Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 14), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 14))
trg.Cells(13 + (TRow - 1) * 3, 5) = C_PR.Value

 Set C_PR = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(TRow, 15), datasheet.Cells(TRow, 15))
trg.Cells(13 + (TRow - 1) * 3, 6) = C_PR.Value

'Find next line in the group from the top row
TRow = TRow + 1
rng = datasheet.Cells(TRow, 7).Value


Set rngcnt = datasheet.Range(datasheet.Cells(2, 7), datasheet.Cells(65536, 7).End(xlUp))
BRow = rngcnt.Rows.Count


Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Lightly tested....

```
Sub ContractPopulate()

 Const START_ROW As Long = 2

 Dim wrk As Workbook
 Dim trg As Worksheet
 Dim datasheet As Worksheet
 Dim rwSrc As Range, grp As String, dRow As Long

    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook
    Set datasheet = wrk.Worksheets("Data")

    Set rwSrc = datasheet.Rows(START_ROW)

    Do While rwSrc.Cells(8).Value <> ""

        grp = rwSrc.Cells(8).Value

        'see if we already have a sheet for this group...
        Set trg = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set trg = wrk.Sheets(grp)
        On Error GoTo 0

        'no sheet created yet, so create it and set it up
        If trg Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Contract").Copy After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count)
            Set trg = wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count)
            trg.Name = grp
            'one-time copy of values....
            trg.Cells(7, 2).Value = rwSrc.Cells(6).Value
            trg.Cells(7, 23).Value = grp
            trg.Cells(8, 2).Value = rwSrc.Cells(5).Value
            trg.Cells(8, 21).Value = rwSrc.Cells(7).Value
        End If

        'copy the rest of the values...

        'not quite sure how your template is laid out
        '  so you may need to adjust this next line
        dRow = trg.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row + 3

        If dRow < 13 Then dRow = 13

        trg.Cells(dRow, 8).Value = rwSrc.Cells(9).Value
        trg.Cells(dRow, 20).Value = rwSrc.Cells(10).Value
        trg.Cells(dRow + 1, 4).Value = rwSrc.Cells(13).Value
        trg.Cells(dRow + 1, 5).Value = rwSrc.Cells(14).Value
        trg.Cells(dRow + 1, 6).Value = rwSrc.Cells(15).Value

        Set rwSrc = rwSrc.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```